# Command prompt use echoed text

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I want to write a little script for the command prompt that finds all the pdfs in the current directory, and outputs the file `conglomerated.tex` which should look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{first.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{second.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{third.pdf}
[...]
\includepdf[pages=-]{last.pdf}    
\end{document}
```

The command to get the pdfs in the current directory (sorted and formatted as I want them) is

```
dir /B /OD *.pdf
```

I just want to take the output from that command and put it into the file as above. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set target=conglomerated.tex
del %target% 1>nul 2>nul

echo \documentclass{article} > %target%
echo \usepackage{pdfpages} >> %target%
echo. >> %target%
echo \begin{document} >> %target%
for /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /B /OD *.pdf') DO echo \includepdf[pages=-]{%%f} >> %target%
echo \end{document} >> %target%
```